# Django Generic DetailView customization

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-generic-views

How exactly can I customize a generic DetailView in Django. For example in my webapp that show all backups in given root directory together with their size, I mostly use generic views to display the content, but I don't have slightest idea how to deal with the customization. This is [Django tutorial - DetailView page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).

This is my DetailView:

```
    class ProjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
        model = Project
        template_name = "projects_portal/details.html"
```

This is my URL:

```
    url(r'^projects_portal/(?P<pk>\d+)/view/$', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name="projects_details"),
```

This is the model:

```
    class Project(models.Model):
        root_dir = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=2000, verbose_name=_(u"project root directory"))
        project_name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"project name"))
        total_backups_size = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u"total backups size"))
        earliest_backup = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u"earliest backup"))
        latest_backup = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u"latest backup"))
```

and this is my .html:

```
{% extends "projects_portal/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Details{% endblock %}

{% block extracss %}
<style>
    div{font-size:24px;}
    .col-md-2{width:400px}
</style>
{% endblock extracss %}

{% block content %}
        <table class="table table table-hover">
            <tr>
             <div class="row top-buffer">
                 <td><div class="col-md-1"><strong>Root directory:</strong></div></td>
                 <td><div class="col-md-2">{{project.root_dir}}</div></td>
            </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="row top-buffer">
                    <td><div class="col-md-1"><strong>Project name:</strong></div></td>
                    <td><div class="col-md-2">{{project.project_name}}</div></td>
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center">
                    <td>
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center"><a href="{% url 'projects_portal' %}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">OK</button></a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </div>
            </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The thing is that I want to add some content in the generic detailView so that it must visualize a list of all subfolders in given project and show their size. I prepared two functions to deal with this problem:

```
    def traverse_dir(path):
            path_len = len(path)
            dir_dict = {}
            for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(path):
                dir_size = get_size(dirName)               
                dir_dict[dirName[path_len:]] = dir_size
            return dir_dict    

    def get_size(start_path = '.'):
        total_size = 0
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
            for f in filenames:
                fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
        return total_size
```

The first one traverses the root directory and use the second one to get the size of each directory. The functions are tested and they are OK. The problem is how to implement them in the generic DetailView.

Answer (score 2):

To add content to your `DetailView` override the `get_context_data` method. For instance, if you add the following method to your `ProjectDetailView` class:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['hello'] = "Hello, world"
    return context
```

you will have an extra context variable named `hello` in your template, so you would output it with `{{ hello }}`.

Hint: [CBV Inspector](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is your friend when you deal with CBVs.

**Update**

OP wanted to pass the directory django is running from to his `traverse_dir` function. To do that, you can add the following to your `settings.py` (django 1.6 adds it by default):

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Now, you can change your `get_context_path` method of `ProjectDetailView` like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['dirs'] = traverse_dir(settings.BASE_PATH)
    return context
```

Now you will have a `dirs` variable in your context which can be outputed using (for instance) a `{% for %}` loop.

*Notice: I haven't checked if `traverse_dir` is working as expected.*

**Update 2**

It turns out the OP had a different question: How to display a folder hierarchy with django. What I'd do is create simple view (not DetailView) named `traverse` and add the following url patterns in my `urls.py`

```
url(r'^traverse/(.+)*', 'views.test.traverse', name='traverse' ),
```

Now, the `traverse` view could be implemented like this:

```
def traverse(request, segments=""):
    segments = segments.split(r'/')
    # segments is an array of the url paths
    # construct the path of the folder you want to view here
    # by concatenate settings.BASE_PATH with the url components

    # finally output the contents of the folder by creating links
    # which concatenate the segments with the contents of the folder
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your post. After sleeping for more than 8 hours the idea is starting to get clear. But I would like to ask how exactly i can pass the root directory that is used in the DetailView to the function that i use for traversing the directories ? I search for some method in [http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/] (CBV Inspector) but i couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: So you want to search the *server-side* directory ? Why do you want to do that ? I really can't think of a reason but in any case I updated the answer.

Comment: Okey, thank you for your patience. I think i will never again make pre - coffe posts (still sleeping). The thing is that i couldn't explain good what exactly is the point. In my webapp BackupViewer  the detailView shows - two things: 1: the name of the project that is clicked and 2: the root directory where it resides. The goal is to show also the list of subfolders in the project and their size. But the problem is that i don't have slightest idea how to traverse the project directory that is visualized in the DetailView, i hope my English don't confuse you too much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you ask is *not* easy. I will update my answer to give you some general hints for this and if you have any other comments please ask in a different question.

Comment: Thank you again for your patience and help. Have a nice day :)